# What are the performance costs of introducing a CLR type (class or interface)?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, clr

Even though .Net allows dynamic invocation (e.g. with reflection, C# dynamic keyword), but when using a language such as C# we sometimes feel it is necessary to use static typing, in order to prove that our program is correct, and will not have typing issues at runtime.

Sometimes this results in us introducing interfaces or base classes that fee like they are just for purpose of explaining to the compiler that 'Yes, I know all the objects I pass to this context are going to be understand invoke Method X with arg Y - here, I will prove it to you using an interface definition!' (For example - .net internally uses IReadChunkBytes interface to allow passing either SteamReadChunkBytes or BufferReadChunkBytes objects to some method or other.)

Other times we create classes or types to serve other purposes which are do not feel very usefully type-y, such as being unique identifiers (a bit like enums) with small attached behavior, or to hold a set of constants, etc.

I'm interested in better understanding what the compiletime, runtime, and other costs are going to be when I face such design decisions where I am asking 'should I define a new type or interface just in order to solve this problem?' Obviously there will be two sides to the cost and benefit in each such comparison, but in general we should hopefully see the same costs for 'define new type' in each such comparison/disucssion. How do we quantify these costs?

Comment: What alternatives are you wanting to compare?  It's not clear to me what's being asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost everything has some runtime cost. The only exception would be things like empty space. The reason is that almost everything gets record in IL image, even local variable names, parameter names, constants. So at least there will be disk cost, virtual memory space cost, working space cost.

In terms of CPU, more metadata will slow down program startup, token resolution, JIT/NGEN.

But sometimes adding types can have positive impact on performance too.

Answer (score 4):

The performance and/or space costs of statically creating a new interface or class are always negligible. Don't think about it too much in this sense. In contrast, reflection and late binding can cause serious performance problems. You should use static typing pretty much at every opportunity.

The costs associated with creating a new class or interface aren't performance costs. They're more human costs. Here is a list of some considerations you should make before adding a new class or interface. At any rate, using late binding or reflection is probably not going to help your program. These are last-resort techniques.

- Program complexity. While this is often not the case, a general rule of the thumb is that every class adds additional complexity to your application, and thus makes it harder to understand during run time, pass on to new project members, remember, and diagram. Changes become more difficult to implement.
- If you really don't feel like a class is necessary, perhaps it isn't. Maybe there are other ways to solve your problem, such as using more dynamic classes. Perhaps you can use inheritance or other techniques to reduce repetitions.

Comment: +1. Nice note about human cost too.

Comment: I really like the point you're making about human cost, but I still disagree with the statement that runtime costs are always negligible. When you're facing a single decision today the small stuff seems negligable, but over time we and our team mates make hundreds or thousands of such decisions, and they will eventually add up to something. Consider what if your decision introduced an architectural pattern which leads to creation of hundreds of types just to satisfy that pattern? OK perhaps that is a different problem too. :) But we must be able to justify why it is a bad pattern...

Answer (score 0):

Using dynamic over strong types is more likely to give you performance issues. So if you are fine with using `dynamic` for most of your objects you may not need to worry about cost of creating static types.

Side note: if you prefer dynamic typing C# may not be the best language to work with. And it would be harder to get good samples as most C# code is targeting strongly typed objects.